# Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '{' in AndroidManifest.xml using Facebook ShareLink

Tags: facebook-android-sdk, facebook-share

Though I delete the "{}" braces but it still occurs.

```
<provider
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider" android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{facebook_app_id}"
        android:exported="true" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same: the IDE re-inserted the curly braces. I cut the part, restarted Android Studio and pasted it. Then it worked.

Answer (score 30):

The format shoud be: `android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0123456789"` , where `012345678` is your `Facebook app ID`. Use it **without** the `{` character. So your `provider` tag should be:

```
<provider
android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider0123456789"
android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
android:exported="true"/>
```

However, if you accidently have already used the `{` character, then you will be most likely facing an Android Studio bug as it is [reported here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=93290). The problem is that you are trying to edit the **wrong manifest**. The poped up manifest from Android Studio *build message* **is not** the application's manifest.

So simply open your application's manifest and you can edit it without problem.

Comment: That's one hell of a bug, and it still exists in v2.1 of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Replace {facebook_app_id} in the snippet you posted with your Facebook app id.

Comment: i think you say as: android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1620994908000000" but when i press the run it becomes android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{1620994908000000}" and show up the error. when i try to edit there is also a message like: Files under the build folder is generated should not edited.

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml would not be in the build folder.

Answer (score 1):

You added the `<provider../>` tag in the wrong place

1. Delete the `<provider../>` tag
2. Close Android Manifest
3. Try "Sync Project with Grandle Files"
4. Build Project again
5. Open Android Manifest
6. Add the   tag, without hte brackets '{}' right before application tag closes

...

```
<provider
    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
    android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider7779..."
    android:exported="true" />
</application>
```

Hope it helps